# How Can I Make This Indirect Cove Lighting Look?

Tags: lighting, ceiling, frame

Just moved in to new house and would love some indirect cove lighting like this in the bedroom I'm decorating...but I'm not sure where to start. I want the box section to protrude around 1ft from the wall and be around 4" high. It can be L-Shaped, no need for top cover. Only needs to support weight of LED strip light and a few down lights.

[image: Cove Lighting I love]

Any advice on frame structure, timber size, general design greatly appreciated.

Comment: ...I guess not :(